# Lua with calculator script

Tags: lua, calculator

I'm trying to create a calculator for my own use . I don't know how to make it so that when the user inputs e.g. 6 for the prompt lets the user type in 6 numbers. So if I wrote 7 , it would give me an option to write 7 numbers and then give me the answer, And if  i wrote 8 it will let me write 8 numbers...

```
if choice == "2" then
    os.execute( "cls" )
    print("How many numbers?")
    amountNo = io.read("*n")
    if amountNo <= 2 then print("You cant have less than 2 numbers.")
    elseif amountNo >= 14 then print("Can't calculate more than 14 numbers.")
    elseif amountNo <= 14 and amountNo >= 2 then
        amountNmb = amountNo
        if amountNmb = 3 then print(" Number 1")
        print("Type in the numbers seperating by commas.")
    local nmb
    print("The answer is..")
```

Comment: Btw is a bit messed up because I unfinished it , so the code like amountNmb variable isnt even needed there etc.

Comment: is there a reason why no answer accepted? is this still open?

Answer (score 0):

The `io.read` formats are a bit limiting.

If you want a comma-separated list to be typed, I suggested reading a whole line and then iterating through each value:

```
local line = io.input("*l")
local total = 0
-- capture a sequence of non-comma chars, which then might be followed by a comma
-- then repeat until there aren't any more
for item in line:gmatch("([^,]+),?") do 
    local value = tonumber(item) 
    -- will throw an error if item does not represent a number
    total = total + value
end 
print(total)
```

This doesn't limit the count of values to any particular value—even an empty list works. (It is flawed in that it allows the line to end with a comma, which is ignored.)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you [want the following](http://ideone.com/BODacy):

```
print "How many numbers?"
amountNo = io.read "*n"
if amountNo <= 2 then
    print "You can't have less than 2 numbers."
elseif amountNo >= 14 then
    print "Can't calculate more than 14 numbers."
else
    local sum = 0
    for i = 1, amountNo do
        print( ('Enter number %s'):format(i) )
        local nmb = io.read '*n'
        sum = sum + nmb
    end
    print( ('The sum is: %s'):format(sum) )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user separates the numbers with commas, they don't need to state how many they want to add, you can just get them all with gmatch. Also with the right pattern you can ensure you only get numbers:

```
local line = io.input() 
local total = 0
-- match any number of digits, skipping any non-digits
for item in line:gmatch("(%d+)") do 
    total = total + item
end
```

With input '4 , 6 , 1, 9,10, 34' (no quotes), then `print(total)` gives 64, the correct answer